# Counting runs in a string

Tags: python, string

I have a string that looks like:

```
string = 'TTHHTHHTHHHHTTHHHTTT'
```

How can I count the number of runs in the string so that I get,

5 runs of T and 4 runs of H

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> strs = 'TTHHTHHTHHHHTTHHHTTT'
>>> Counter(k for k, g in groupby(strs))
Counter({'T': 5, 'H': 4})
```

`itertools.groupby` groups the item based on a key.(by default key is the items in the iterable itself)

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint([(k, list(g)) for k, g in groupby(strs)])
[('T', ['T', 'T']),
 ('H', ['H', 'H']),
 ('T', ['T']),
 ('H', ['H', 'H']),
 ('T', ['T']),
 ('H', ['H', 'H', 'H', 'H']),
 ('T', ['T', 'T']),
 ('H', ['H', 'H', 'H']),
 ('T', ['T', 'T', 'T'])]
```

Here first item is the key(`k`) based on which the items were grouped and `list(g)` is the group related to that key. As we're only interested in `key` part, so, we can pass `k` to `collections.Counter` to get the desired answer.

Comment: great one, never knew that python groupby works different from SQL one, thanks, +1. It's a pity I have no time to work with python at work :(

Answer (score 2):

For variety, an `re`-based approach

```
import re
letters = ['H', 'T']
matches = re.findall(r'({})\1*'.format('|'.join(letters)), 'TTHHTHHZTHHHHTTHHHTTT')      
print matches
['T', 'H', 'T', 'H', 'T', 'H', 'T', 'H', 'T']
[(letter, matches.count(letter)) for letter in letters]
[('H', 4), ('T', 5)]
```